# C - irc bot skeleton

Tags: c, winapi, bots, irc

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int PORT = 6667;
const char *SERVER = "irc.freenode.org";
const char *CHAN = "#channela";
const char *NICK = "loveMilk";

const int MAX_BUFF_SIZE = 512;

int sock_conn(SOCKET *socketn, const char *HOST, int portn);
int sock_send(SOCKET *socketn, char* msg, ...);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    char buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    char oBuff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    int buffRec;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata) != 0)
        return 0;

    SOCKET sock;

    if(sock_conn(&sock, SERVER, PORT) != 0)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("connected.\n");

    sock_send(&sock, "USER %s \"\" \"127.0.0.1\" :%s\r\n", NICK, NICK);
    sock_send(&sock, "NICK %s\r\n", NICK);
    Sleep(100);

    sock_send(&sock, "JOIN %s\r\n", CHAN);
    printf("Joined channel.\n");

    while(1)
    {
        memset(buff, 0, MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
        memset(oBuff, 0, MAX_BUFF_SIZE);

        buffRec = recv(sock, buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, 0);
        if((buffRec == 0) || (buffRec == SOCKET_ERROR)) break;

        if(buff[0] != ':')
        {
            strcpy(oBuff, "PONG :");
            printf("PONG");
            sock_send(&sock, oBuff);
        }
        else
        {
            if(strstr(buff, "PRIVMSG"))
            {
                int i, num = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < strlen(buff); ++i) if(buff[i] = ' ') ++num;
                char** parts = malloc(sizeof(char*) * num);
                char *p;
                p = strtok(buff, " ");
                int j = 0;
                while(p != NULL)
                {
                    parts[j] = p;
                    j++;
                    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }

                free(parts);
            }
        }
    }
    closesocket(sock);
    return 1;
}

int sock_conn(SOCKET *socketn, const char *HOST, int portn)
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    SOCKADDR_IN sockA;
    LPHOSTENT hostE;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata) == -1) return -1;
    if(!(hostE = gethostbyname(HOST)))
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    if ((*socketn = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    sockA.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockA.sin_port = htons(portn);
    sockA.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*hostE->h_addr_list);

    if(connect(*socketn, (LPSOCKADDR)&sockA, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
}

int sock_send(SOCKET *socketn, char* msg, ...)
{
    char buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, msg);
    vsprintf(buff, msg, va);
    va_end(va);
    send(*socketn, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
    return 1;
}
```

If I try to print `buff` after the `if(strstr(buff, "PRIVMSG"))` it crashes.

The while with the `strtok` won't work, if I try to reach `parts[0]` it crashes.

I tried to print `parts[0]` but shows nothing, tried to print during the while loop, shows nothing.
why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't terminate your strings!

Edit the receiving part as this:

```
buffRec = recv(sock, buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, 0);
if((buffRec == 0) || (buffRec == SOCKET_ERROR)) break;

/* New line: Terminate buffer as a string */
buff[buffRec] = '\0';
```

Comment: still all the parts are null.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, a character array must end with '\0' to be considered a string. I think that C doesn't distinguish between the two, but you need the '\0' to signify the end of string. This could be why `strstr(buff, "PRIVMSG"))` isn't returning anything. It may default to null (thus not satisfying your `if`) because it doesn't think it has been passed a string.

'strtok(string, delimiter)' breaks an input string into tokens by using the delimiter. Here, you have passed it NULL as its string and " " as its delimiter. I am unfamiliar with many string functions (still learning C myself), but I think this is incorrect usage in your code.

`parts[]` does not seem to be defined in the code you've given. Its first use is where you try to store data in it for the inner `while` loop. Are there any other parts to the program that are not shown?